# ¿Cómo recorrer dos tablas en sql para hacer un calculo con los campos?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Buen día a todos, requiero de su ayuda.

Estoy intentando hacer un calculo en una tabla, pero hay que recorrer otra para sacar ese calculo. Me explico.

Tengo dos tablas, las dos tienen registros en fecha desde el 2010 hasta el 2022, para este caso solo necesito los registros del 2022, en ambas tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las dos tablas tienen los mismos registros para el año 2022.

Estos son los datos que necesito, se los muestro ordenados para hacerme entender pero en realidad el orden es otro. Como pueden ver tengo 5 bocatomas y 5 ríos que están registrados para un periodo diferente en la misma fecha (son 24 periodos para un día, por eso se repiten los ríos y bocatomas. Recuerden que los registros son para todo el año)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que actualizar el campo FACTOR_AJUSTE de la tabla Fact_Caudal_Disponible, teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente:

- La fecha y el periodo debe ser el mismo para realizar el calculo
- Si el valor de la bocatoma 1 dividido el valor del rio 1 es mayor a 1, entonces que coloque un 1. sino entonces que coloque el valor de la división.

Así quedaría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me haya hecho entender. Intente hacerlo con un cursor anidado pero se demora mucho el proceso, y es que no se como mas recorrer dos tablas, ¿hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?. Se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrar que intentaste? porque usaste un cursor? un update con un join no te sirvio?

Comment: En SQL Server es sencillo hacer eso mediante un UPDATE con JOIN, pero escribir los datos de prueba toma tiempo y sería mejor que los incluyeras como texto en vez de hacerlo como imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando manejamos bases de datos SQL debemos de olvidarnos de indicar como hacer las cosas para indicar que es lo que se quiere hacer. SQL Server tiene múltiples algoritmos eficientes para recorrer las tablas sin que tengamos que generarlos nosotros. Para poder cambiar esta mentalidad, necesitamos dejar de pensar que queremos hacer con la fila y empezar a pensar en que queremos hacer con la columna.

Lo primero que hacemos, es tratar de unir las tablas y por ello empezamos con lo básico que es un `SELECT` y un `JOIN` para unirlas.

```
SELECT *
FROM Fact_Caudal_Bocatoma   fcb --Asignamos alias a las tablas para referenciarlas más fácilmente.
JOIN Fact_Caudal_Disponible fcd ON  fcb.fecha    = fcd.fecha --Incluimos todos los campos que usamos para combinar las tablas.
                                AND fcb.periodo  = fcd.periodo
                                AND fcb.bocatoma = fcd.rio;
```

Después de eso, ya tenemos todas las filas de ambas tablas con la relación correcta. Ahora nos podemos concentrar en la fórmula. Para el condicional dentro de una sentencia `SELECT` usamos `CASE`.

```
SELECT *,
    -- Fórmula según se explica en la pregunta
    CASE WHEN fcb.valor / fcd.valor > 1 THEN 1 ELSE fcb.valor / fcd.valor END,
    -- Fórmula simplificada
    CASE WHEN fcb.valor > fcd.valor THEN 1 ELSE fcb.valor / fcd.valor END
FROM Fact_Caudal_Bocatoma   fcb --Asignamos alias a las tablas para referenciarlas más fácilmente.
JOIN Fact_Caudal_Disponible fcd ON  fcb.fecha    = fcd.fecha --Incluimos todos los campos que usamos para combinar las tablas.
                                AND fcb.periodo  = fcd.periodo
                                AND fcb.bocatoma = fcd.rio;
```

Por último, cambiamos el `SELECT` por `UPDATE` y usamos la fórmula para asignar el valor a la columna correspondiente.

```
UPDATE fcd SET --Usamos el alias de la tabla que vamos a actualizar
    factor_ajuste = CASE WHEN fcb.valor > fcd.valor THEN 1 ELSE fcb.valor / fcd.valor END
FROM Fact_Caudal_Bocatoma   fcb --Asignamos alias a las tablas para referenciarlas más fácilmente.
JOIN Fact_Caudal_Disponible fcd ON  fcb.fecha    = fcd.fecha --Incluimos todos los campos que usamos para combinar las tablas.
                                AND fcb.periodo  = fcd.periodo
                                AND fcb.bocatoma = fcd.rio;

--Verificamos que todo esté bien
SELECT *
FROM Fact_Caudal_Disponible;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda.